# Complicated CSS layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, css-float

Could somebody help me with freaking complicated tile layout as is specified under [this link](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/4002/picture2rcp.png)?

I have tried to use float:left for widgets but I getting the red block always below #2.
I should be able to dynamically add widgets to black dashboard. I can use html5, css3 and jquery.

There are not just 2 columns. If the dashboard has free width space for 3rd, 4th, etc... then it should be there. There cound be one to infinite number of widgets with different size. If there is no free width space then new widgets should float down to left and totally fill free space.

Failing markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="Robots" content="noindex, nofollow"/>
    <style type="text/css">
      #dashboard {
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        background: #000;
        width: 320px;
        float: left;
      }
      div.widget {
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
        float: left;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="dashboard">
      <div class="widget" style="background: #fff; width: 120px; height: 150px">
        <h3>#1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="widget" style="background: #fff; width: 120px; height: 250px">
        <h3>#2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="widget" style="background: red; width: 90px; height: 50px">
        <h3>#3</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="widget" style="background: green; width: 90px; height: 50px">
        <h3>#4</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="widget" style="background: blue; width: 90px; height: 50px">
        <h3>#5</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</body>
```

Additional mockup: img191.imageshack.us/img191/2139/picture2fdi.png

Comment: Can you post the source code for this?

Comment: http://pastie.org/593815

Answer (score 2):

make 2 container divs, both float:left

then just float:left everything inside those divs.

easiest way to do a two column layout with css.

```
<div id="leftcol">
your code...
</div>
<div id="rightcol">
your code...
</div>
```

css:

```
leftcol,rightcol{float:left;width:(whatever);}
```

Answer (score 2):

The CSS:

```
body {
  background: #000;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: left;
}
.widget {
    margin: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 200px;
}
.content {
    margin: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 300px;
}
#one {
    height: 300px;
}
#two {
    height: 400px;
}
#red {
    background: #f00;
    height: 100px;
}
#green {
    background: #0f0;
    height: 100px;
}
#blue {
    background: #00f;
    height: 100px;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="content" id="one"></div>
    <div class="widget" id="red"></div>
    <div class="widget" id="green"></div>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <div class="content" id="two"></div>
    <div class="widget" id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are not just 2 columns. If the dashboard has free width space for 3rd, 4th, etc... then it should be there.

Comment: Hmmm.. I didn't know about those conditions.  Maybe you can update your question to include those conditions?

Comment: What are the other conditions? Are the #1 and #2 divs fixed? And there cound be one to infinite number of widgets?

Comment: There cound be one to infinite number of widgets with different size.

Comment: And where do you want these widget to go based on different conditions?

Comment: My first impression is that it won't give a good user experience.

Comment: I don't think so, these widgets are just informers. Like an OSX dashboard widgets but automatically positioned to fill free space

Answer (score 2):

I know this is probably too late. But I recently found this JQuery plugin that seems to solve the problem in a very elegant way.

[isotope.metafizzy.co](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about using BlueprintCSS? http://www.blueprintcss.org/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just including a wrapper div, classing it as something like "widget" and floating it left? I'm not sure I understand what the colored boxes are underneath #1 and #2 are, but if they are related to the items directly above them, I don't see how this is difficult:

```
<div class="widget">
    <div id="widget1">stuff</div>
    <div id="widget1_1">stuff related to 1</div>
</div>

<div class="widget">
    <div id="widget2">stuff</div>
    <div id="widget2_1">stuff related to 2</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.widget {float: left; overflow: auto;}
.widget div {float: left;}
```

Comment: Doing the same. That is not exactly what I want. I edited my question again. See my reply to phoenix for my failing markup.

Comment: ha, well, with that additional picture you posted, that's a little different than your original question. also, good luck trying to implement that layout.

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS solution for what you want. I think I have seen JS solutions floating around, but I can't put my finger on any at the moment.